# Configure different store views on single website - magento

Tags: php, mysql, multistore

I am trying to create three store views in `single` magento website.Named as `US`, `UK` and `saudi arabia`.

Each store view is differ from  `language` and  `currency` of other store views. But catalog and customers are same.

Some of the magento developers were told, Which is impossible to setup different languages and different currencies on different store views within same website. It is only possible to create different websites.

Simply my problem is, when `US` users visit my website, page content should be shown as `English` language and currency should be  mentioned as `US dollar`. And when `Saudi Arabia` users visit my website, page content should be changed into `Arabic language` and currency should be changed into `Saudi Riyal`. IS it possible?

Comment: The problem with the currency is, that a currency is nailed to a website(?) and you can only add an exchange rate as Marius describes. Therefore your price in real is in your base currency and only calculated. The payment is made in the base currency (afaik). So you can show different currencies but be careful with the base currency and payment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
To set the language for each store view, go to `System->Configuration->General`.
Now select each store view from the top left selector and change the field `Locale` from the section `Locale Options` to what you need (English Us for US and so on).

Now set up the currencies.

Go to `System->Configuration->Currency Setup`.
Do the following for each store view as you did in the previous step.
Set the field `Allowed Currencies` and `Default Display Currency` for each store view as you need it. USD for US website, and so on.

Now go to System->Manage Currency Rates and fill in an exchange rate for each currency you see there.